# Do I need to buffer these sensor outputs in this scenario?

Tags: sensor, datasheet

I'm planning to use [this](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00190424-discovery-kit-for-stm32f7-series-with-stm32f746ng-mcu-stmicroelectronics.pdf) uC board's LCD to read the humidity and temperature sensors' outputs.

**[Here](https://docs.rs-online.com/192b/0900766b8144ea72.pdf)** is the datasheet for the humidity and **[here](https://docs.rs-online.com/d67c/0900766b81384408.pdf)** is for the pressure sensor.

Since the ADC of the uC is 3.3V range. The sensors are max 5V output so I will use a resistor divider like such as below:

[image]

I will measure the precise ratio for the resistor divider above to implement in uC code.

Humidity sensor datasheet has the following figure:

[image]

Do I need to buffer the sensor outputs before the divider if I don't want to introduce resistor divider loading error down to 5%? I cannot find the output impedance of the sensors.

**EDIT:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're violating minimum load requirement. Minimum load requirement is 80kOhm, so your total resistance at the sensor output has to be below that to ensure stability. With your circuit total resistance in path to ground is 100kOhm, is too much.

Proof: [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10283/what-is-a-minimum-load)

Considering that, it looks like you can get away without buffer. Of course, you can always provide minimum load and then buffer it, it will probably be the cleanest way as long as the buffer has low noise and offsets, but I don't think it will change performance by noticable value unless you wanna go megaaccurate. Besides, there is not much info in datasheets regarding output voltage change vs output current. So you can only try it, I'm afraid. Didn't find any minimum load for pressure sensor, so I would probably buffer it and then attach or not attach minimum load resistor before buffer. That way you have a ready circuit where you can simply attach and detach load at your wish. Sensor - Buffer - Voltage divider - MCU. You either put a resistor to ground before buffer or not and see the result. Again, pick op amps carefully. Rail-to-rail, low offset voltage, bias current etc.

Comment: Thanks can this be a fine buffer https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LT1006.pdf? It doesnt say rail to rail but says precision opmap. I have it at the momment.

Comment: it can output in the range of 25mV - 4.0V (if no load or some hundred kiloohms). It's called output swing  characteristic. It basically shows minimum and maximum output. If that's enough for your purposes, you can use it of course. By the way, don't go with superhigh resistors for voltage divider when you feed it into MCU. I didn't think about it, but MCU's input impedance is not infinite. STM32F103C8T6 blue pill MCU has input resistance of 20k only for example. So your voltage divider should be an order of magnitude smaller resistance to avoid inaccuracy. Depends on ur MCU of course.

Comment: You can always buffer voltage divider output too :) there are chips made of two op amps - perfect for two buffers

Comment: I cannot find the output impedance of the sensor. I also cannot find the input impedance of the uC's ADC. So many unknowns. So I think to buffer both after the sensor and the divider is needed as you say. But do you think LM324 suffice for such https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm324-n.pdf?ts=1593598036340&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F?

Comment: output impedance of sensor is not really that relevant. Enough to say it's small. Probably some 50 Ohm or less. We're going to have kiloohms anyway. MCU probably has some 20k if it's built similarly to STM32F103C8T6. But if everything is buffered, it doesn't matter. If your op amp has 5V supply voltage, it should MOSTLY to be enough.

Comment: You're outputting at most 3.3V, which is well within its 0.025 - 4.0 output voltage range. So yeah. Sensor - Minimum load (resistance LOWER than shown in minimum load, so 20k or 50k to ground will work) - Buffer - Buffer outputs to voltage divider - Buffer 2 - MCU ADC Pin. The only problem is if your sensor outputs some 4.5V. Your op amp will clamp it at 4V. So as long as your sensor doesn't output close to its maximum, you'll be good.

Comment: "Your op amp will clamp it at 4V.". Which opamp? I was asking about LM324

Comment: yeah I meant it. The datasheet says it can't output more than 4V with 5V supply. So the first buffer from the sensor will cut outputs of 4-5V to 4V output

Comment: I see that could be a problem since 100kPa (typical value) corresponds to 4V. I guess I need find rail to rail as you said.

Comment: If the output impedance is negligible I might use this circuit https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfHq4.png What do you think? The ADC0 is t sense the supply voltage since the sensor is ratiometric.

Comment: Looks like a good idea. But if your sensor will give nonsense, you can always buffer the sensor and separate it from voltage divider. But the circuit you showed is worth a try at least. I think it should work. That op amp also has max output voltage of 4V tho, it won't work as a buffer between sensor and voltage divider, but after divider it will work ok since max input will be 3.3, so will be the max output, so no problem there. I would just find a rail-to-rail op amp and use the same part twice to buffer both. But yeah, it may very well work as it is